# is it correct to add self like in this case in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, self

I am trying to make it available to repost a post in my app...I see in a Youtube video this code..

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :bio
belongs_to :user

mount_uploader :image, PictureUploader

def repost
    repost_pin = self.dup
    repost_pin.save
end
```

is it correct to use self like here? and would it be possible to change to this:

```
def repost
    dub
end
```

in the end repost will be called on the instance variable  @post(@post = Post.find(params[:id]) ) .... maybe I misunderstanding something here...anyone can help?

Comment: You ask if it is possible to change to the second `repost` method, why don't you try changing it to that and running your application? and post if there are any errors?

Comment: The main thing that I want to know that If it is right to use self like the way used here...is it a correct way in ruby or what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip `self` when it is clear from context that you are reading a current instance's attribute or calling its method.

When writing you should be more careful as this:

```
def write
  test = 'test'
end
```

will create a local variable `test` even if there is an attribute with the same name. Alternatively, this:

```
def write
  self.test = 'test'
end
```

will assign the value to current instance's attribute named `test`.

In your example you could skip `self` since `dup` is a method of `Object` and therefore is available in current context as a valid identifier:

```
def repost
    repost_pin = dup
    repost_pin.save
end
```

That said, it is not an error to explicitly use `self` e.g., to mark your intent to use the object's attribute or method. [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-self-unless-required) does not recommend it though.

Comment: great explanation...thank you for your help ;) just to be clear...when calling repost on @post...it will be like that: repost_pin = @post.dup?? am i correct?

Comment: When I try you vote it app I get a message that I have less that 15 repetition so I cant vote

Comment: It's not about the vote but about the accepting. Please read [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: It's worth noting there's a number of Ruby style guides and no one is canonical. They do overlap significantly in their advice but differ in important ways.